Multiple logs coming for a web app hosted in Azure App service
I have a web app which has a service using BackgroundService. I have registered this as singleton as I am deploying this web app to Azure App service with P1V3 plan with 3 instances. The web app uses Serilog for logging and dumps the logs in Application Insights.
Currently I am getting 3 logs for the same message. I am guessing this is coming from the three instances, but I want the service to run as a singleton. In short, I want only one instance to run at a time and generate logs accordingly.
Is there something I am missing or is there a different approach to this?

Please share your code and configuration of ApplicationInsights.

It is the same as App service - hosted in NE, P1V3 plan

Share your code..

Could you elaborate what code are you referring to

Your Program.cs , .csproj files and serilog configuration.

Are you following any doc ?

What does you mean by deployed to 3 instances?

maybe this pattern can help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/leader-election. An implementation can be found here

@PeterBons leader election process is definitely a way to ensure it and I am debating the same
